# How many Conspiracy Cards are allowed in a deck

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can anyone tell me how many Conspiracy Cards are allowed in a single deck.

I am planning on using 3 of them in one game is that allowed, or is it only one per game.

[Adriana's Valor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdriana%27s%5d%2b%5bValor%5d)

Answer (score 7):

The rules for conspiracy cards are listed in [section 313](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Conspiracies) of the comprehensive rules. Two of the relevant rules from that section are

> - **313.1.** Conspiracy cards are used only in limited play, particularly in the Conspiracy Draft variant (see rule 905). Conspiracy cards aren’t used in constructed play.
> - **313.2.** At the start of a game, before decks are shuffled, each player may put any number of conspiracy cards from his or her sideboard into the command zone. Conspiracy cards with hidden agenda are put into the command zone face down. (See rule 702.105, “Hidden Agenda.”)

So you can have any number, but only in a limited format like draft or sealed. Outside of a format like that, you shouldn't use conspiracies at all.

Answer (score 3):

The only formats that conspiracy cards have been legal in are limited formats, draft and sealed, though Conspiracy is mostly played in draft. These formats do not have any limits on the number of cards of any type that can be used.

> **313.1** Conspiracy cards are used only in limited play, particularly in the Conspiracy Draft variant (see rule 905). Conspiracy cards aren’t used in constructed play.

The conspiracies are the cards from Conspiracy that were not made legacy legal, while all other cards were.

It's worth knowing though that these cards are also not 'in' your deck, conspiracies do not count towards your deck size limit, so you still need the 40 card minimum deck size for the limited formats.

If of course you want to house rule allowing them in your play group, then it is up to you how you limit them, and you should limit them! In constructed play they really are overpowered. Also some of them only work in Limited formats at all, like [Worldknit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorldknit%5d), since you have no "card pool" outside of draft and limited.